# Angular migration from 12 to 13 getting error : Cannot destructure property 'styles' of 'buildOptions.sourceMap' as it is undefined

Tags: angular, migration, ngx-build-plus

Im trying to upgrade my angular version from 12 to 13
but getting error
"An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot destructure property 'styles' of 'buildOptions.sourceMap' as it is undefined."

Im using below command which is provide on offitial site
npx @angular/cli@13 update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13

please anyone can help me

Comment: it seems that adding `sourceMap` configuration to the `angular.json` should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a valid spot to add `sourceMap` configuration in `angular.json`. What I did do successfully was reset the file by creating a new project and copying the contents of the new `angular.json` to my old project and then change the project name everywhere that is doesn't match.

An example version of that file is below:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "temp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/temp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "temp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "temp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "temp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "temp"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted package-lock.json, deleted the node_modules folder and did npm install and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone encounters this issue when upgrading from Angular 12 to 13, just need to

> replace this text '**@ngx-env/builder**' with '**@angular-devkit/build-angular**' in angular.json

Comment: I had similar error cos we were using custom-webpack in angular.json. Removing and using default build configuration helped.

` "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser", `
to

`"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",`

 for example

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed on version 2.0.1.
If you encounter the same issue would you please open an issue on the GitHub repo https://github.com/chihab/ngx-env/issues?

PS: I am the author of the package :)